# The next hop instance must have canIpForward set

Tags: google-compute-engine

Trying to configure a VPN connection using openswan on an existing instance. I can connect to the ipsec interface, can see packets going in from the client with "tcpdump -i ppp0" but no response packets. I have set up a route for the vpn link and it is showing "cannot forward ip traffic. The next hop instance must have canIpForward set." for my current instance.

Searching around I found https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#canipforward which makes me think I need to set up a new instance with the canipforward flag set.

Am I on the right track? What is the easiest way to take my existing instance and rebuild it to have the canipforward flag set?

Answer (score 4):

IP Forward flag needs to be set at the time of instance creation. In your case you can delete the instance keep the disk and than create new instance using the same disk as boot disk, or if you want to be more safe you can take the snapshot of your disk and than create a new instance with that snapshot.

Comment: That worked. Through the web interface I entered the details to create the new instance, but then retrieved the command line and added to it "--can_ip_forward=true". My new instance was created from the command line. There does not appear to be an option to create an ip_forward instance with the web interface. Thanks Faiz.

Comment: In order to allow ip forwarding for instance created through web you need to click on "show advanced options" on the top and enable IP forwarding.

Comment: There is no "show advanced options" in their interface any more. I was only able to add IP forwarding on the command-line by adding "--can-ip-forward".